# Preg_Match result not working to verify username?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am attempting to use preg_match to verify that a username does not contain any special characters. But regardless of what I add into the username field, it is not throwing the error.

Here is my code on my signup page:

```
if (invalidUid($uid) !== false) {
    header("location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduid");
        exit();
  }
```

Here is the code on my function page

```
function invalidUid($username) {
    $result;
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
        $result = true;
    }
    else {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What inputs are you testing in `invalidUid()`? I notice that you use `*` instead of `+` at the end - this will allow a blank value for `$username` since `*` matches zero or more characters.

Comment: It is important to ensure you have all errors reported when debugging a header() call. At the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` - because a lot of things can interfere with a Location header and you won't know it unless you display warnings.

Comment: I am testing a text input for usernames. Trying to ensure that they cannot use special characters in this field. Which they are able to currently.

Comment: Works for me. You can simplify your function like: `return preg_match('/[^a-z\d]/i', $username);`

Comment: @R3gulate108 we can see the purpose of what you are testing, but I am asking you to post _exactly_ the input values you are using to test this function and where it is failing. It should work except for the case of an empty string, so you might have a fault elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match up your parentheses

Not like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"), $username)
```

but like this:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username))
```

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance but is that not how I have it in the example?

Comment: Nope! But Really Close, just try copy and paste the second line i posted

Comment: This is **exactly** what OP wrote!